# Ruby selenium test with CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, circleci

I am facing a problem running selenium tests with CircleCI service. If I try to test my ruby application's login functionality:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://0.0.0.0:3000"

driver.find_element(:name, 'user[email]').send_keys('eser@email.com')
driver.find_element(:name, 'user[password]').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element(:name, 'commit').click
```

On local machine it works perfectly, but with CircleCI test fails. To be more specific, looks like on CircleCI my tests cannot access localhost (tried curl localhost:3000 in  CircleCI test box - nothing found). I also tried changing 0.0.0.0 to localhost as well as to 127.0.0.1 - still same result. If I try very similar test for testing google's search (driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com", etc.) it works with no problem. Tried to contact CircleCI - no response so far. Any ideas how to get my test pass, or at least how to get my application address when it is on CircleCI server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run tests, you need to have a selenium grid up and running.  It works locally, because your box can run selenium tests.. CircleCI cannot run tests, it's just a CI.

What you need to do, is in your project, have your selenium tests point at a grid.

```
http://somegrid:4444/wd/register
```

Comment: Interesting, as in that test I have driver.title, driver.current_url which returns right values when I run google search test in CircleCI, which I assume means selenium itself is running well, am I wrong?